# How to deduce circle theorems in Wolfram language?

Tags: geometry, theorem-proving, synthetic-geometry

I can deduce the first one by applying `FindGeometricConjectures` on the following scene:

```
GeometricScene[{
    "A","B","C"
},{
    Line[{{"A","B"},{"B","C"}}],CircleThrough[{"A","B","C"},Midpoint[{"A","C"}]]
}]
```

Next one:

```
GeometricScene[{
    "A","B","C","D"
},{
    Line[{{"A","B"},{"B","C"},{"A","D"},{"D","C"}}],CircleThrough[{"A","B","C","D"}]
}]
```

But the following is not working:

```
GeometricScene[{
    "A","B","C","D"
},{
    Line[{{"A","B"},{"B","C"},{"A","D"},{"D","C"}}],CircleThrough[{"A","B","C"},"D"]
}]
```

Comment: With v12.1.1 on a Mac for the third example I get `{EuclideanDistance["C",  "D"] == EuclideanDistance["D",  "A"]}`. What result do you get that indicates that it is not working?

Comment: @BobHanlon I also get the same on 12.1 but this is not the result I am after. This result is pretty obvious since `CircleThrough[{"A","B","C"},"D"]` means they are both radius. But the result I am after is `PlanarAngle[{"A", "D", "C"}] == 2 PlanarAngle[{"A", "B", "C"}]`

Comment: Then I recommend that you edit your question to show what you tried, what you got, what you expected and why.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that MMA can not find the general result but a special situation such as `PlanarAngle` equal to 30 Degree.

Here is my test.

```
FindGeometricConjectures[
 RandomInstance@
  GeometricScene[{"A", "B", "C", 
    "D"}, {GeometricAssertion[{"C", "D"}, {"SameSide", 
      Line[{"A", "B"}]}], CircleThrough[{"A", "B", "C"}, "D"], 
    PlanarAngle[{"A", "C", "B"}, "Counterclockwise"] == 30 \[Degree], 
    Line[{{"D", "A"}, {"D", "B"}}]}]]
```

[image]

[image]